# Norm of a multiplier of a right-ideal in C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ideals

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra.

If $I$ is an essential two-sided ideal in $A$, then it is fact that for every $a \in A$ we have $\|a\| = \sup_{x \in I, \|x\|=1} \|xa\|$. The argument is that we have an injective (since the ideal is essential) $C^*$-map of $A$ into the multiplier algebra of $I$, which due to injectivity must be isometric.

I need now the corresponding result for right-ideals, i.e., assume now that $I$ is an essential right-ideal in $A$. Do we still have $\|a\| = \sup_{x \in I, \|x\|=1} \|xa\|$ for every $a \in A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The $\sigma(A^{**},A^*)$-closure of $I$ in the second dual von Neumann algebra $A^{**}$ is an ultraweakly closed right ideal, which is of the form $pA^{**}$ for some projection $p$. (In fact $p$ is the ultrastrong limit of any left approximate unit of $I$.) Thus,
$$\sup_{x\in I,\ \|x\|=1}\| xa \| = \sup_{x\in A^{**},\ \|x\|=1}\| pxa \|$$ 
for every $a\in A^{**}$. Consider the central support projection $z$ of $p$ in $A^{**}$. Since $Ia$ is nonzero for every nonzero $a\in A$, the $*$-homomorphism $A\ni a\mapsto za \in zA^{**}$ is faithful. Now, let $a\in A$ be given. For any $\epsilon>0$, the projection $q:=z1_{[\|a\|-\epsilon,\|a\|]}(|aa^*|^{1/2})$ in $zA^{**}$ is nonzero and so there is a nonzero partial isometry $v$ in $zA^{**}$ such that $v=pv=vq$. It follows that 
$$\sup_{x\in A^{**},\ \|x\|=1}\| pxa \| \geq \| pva \| \geq \|a\|-\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Another proof is to use Kadison's transitivity theorem in combination with the following fact: if $J$ is an essential ideal in $A$, then $\|a \|=\sup_\pi\|\pi(a)\|$, where $\pi$ runs over irreducible $*$-representations of $A$ which do not kill $J$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your argument. Why do we have $v=pv$?

Comment: The existence of $v$ follows from comparison theory of projections, but here's a proof. Since $q$ is dominated by the central cover $z$ of $p$, one has $pA^{**}q\neq\{0\}$. Pick any nonzero $x\in pA^{**}q$ and consider the polar decomposition $x=v|x|$. The nonzero partial isometry $v$ belongs to $pA^{**}q$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm confused by the last step. We have $\|pva\| = \|vqa\|$ and I see that $\|qa\| \ge \|a\|-\varepsilon$. But how do you let the $v$ disappear for this estimate?

Comment: By construction, $qa$ is near to a partial isomery and so 
any nonzero "segment" of $qa$ has norm at least $\|a\|-\varepsilon$. 
To be precise, since $aa^*\geq(\|a\|-\varepsilon)^2q$, 
one gets $\|va\|^2=\|vaa^*v^*\|\geq(\|a\|-\varepsilon)^2\|vv^*\|$.

Comment: How to show that the $\sigma(A^{**},A^*)$-closure of $I$ is of  the form $pA^{**}$ for some projection $p$?

Comment: @mathbeginner: It's a standard fact that any SOT-closed right ideal $J$ in a von Neumann algebra is of that form; Consider the unit $p$ of the von Neumann algebra $J\cap J^*$.